# Excel find duplicates in two tables and display related data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, vba

Let's say I've got two tables with two columns. In both cases, the first column consists of a name and a second column consist string of characters with the similar pattern. It looks like this:

Table 1

```
Peter   xxxxx01
John    xxxxx01
Bill    xxxxx01
William xxxxx01
```

Table 2

```
Richard xxxxx02
John    xxxxx02
Bill    xxxxx02
Arthur  xxxxx02
```

Now, I'd like to compare these two tables, find values where the names are duplicated and display data stored in second columns, just like this:

```
(Peter excluded)
John    xxxxx01 xxxxx02
Bill    xxxxx01 xxxxx02
(William, Arthur excluded)
```

I am familiar with pivot tables, however, it won't allow doing this.
I've also tried messing with index match formulas but without much success.
Any advices?

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow!** This is a place for programmers to ask/answer questions when a solution to the problem can't be found elsewhere. Please see the [tour] as well as "[ask]", plus there's important tips about **providing examples** at "[mcve]". Please show that you made an **effort** to find a solution yourself before asking for help (on a _specific_ issue). You can always [edit] your question to include details (code/screenshots/etc) showing what you've tried so far. More info: [help/on-topic]. See also [these great tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: ...Try copy & pasting your question's title into Google and see if you find anything to help.  Here's a couple to get you started: "[Merge two excel files using a common column](https://superuser.com/q/366647/774713)" and "Office.com : [How can I merge two or more tables? (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-can-i-merge-two-or-more-tables-c80a9fce-c1ab-4425-bb96-497dd906d656)".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VLOOKUP function for this.

If your "Table1" is in B3:C6, and your "Table 2" is in F3:G6, then you can use the following formula in D3:D6 to lookup the values in table 2;

Cell D3: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,$F$3:$G$6,2,FALSE),"")

This is first looking up the name in table 1 (Cell B3) against table 2 (F3:G6), and returning the second column of table 2 if it finds the name. If it doesn't find the name, it will return an error, so we wrap the VLOOKUP in an "IFERROR" function, and replace any errors with an empty string, so it looks a bit friendlier. This results in the following table;

```
   A        B        C         D         E        F       G              
1
2           Table 1            Result             Table 2    
3           Peter    xxxxxx01                     Richard xxxxxx02
4           John     xxxxxx01  xxxxxx02           John    xxxxxx02
5           Bill     xxxxxx01  xxxxxx02           Bill    xxxxxx02
6           William  xxxxxx01                     Arthur  xxxxxx02
```

You can then filter on the (Non-Blanks) in column D to only get the results you're interested in.